# NDSolve 1/0 error

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm having trouble to solve a differential equation with NDSolve. Does anyone knows how can I get rid of this problem?

```
data = {To -> 280.5, Ta -> 254, Bir -> 0.0012, 
  Bic -> 0.1206, Bim -> -1.5496}

Uo = To/Ta;

e1 = (1/(x^2))*D[(x^2)*D[U[x, t], x], x] == D[U[x, t], t]

e2 = U[x, t] == Uo /. t -> 0

e3 = D[U[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0

e4 = -D[U[x, t], x] == 
   Bic*(U[x, t] - 1) + Bim + Bir*(U[x, t]^4 - 1) /. x -> 1

sys = Flatten[{e1, e2, e3, e4} /. data]

solNDSolve = 
 NDSolve[sys, U, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.5 /. data}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

Comment: In your expression for `e1`, instead of dividing by $x^2$ on the left, you should multiply by it on the right.

Comment: Thanks @LouisB. I did that and other error appears

Comment: NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.

Comment: NDSolve::ivres: NDSolve has computed initial values that give a zero residual for the differential-algebraic system, but some components are different from those specified. If you need them to be satisfied, giving initial conditions for all dependent variables and their derivatives is recommended.